# Get paginated records and total records in one mongodb aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my monogdb **departments** data structure like as shown below

```
[{
    category: "ABC",
    sections: [
        {
            section_hod: "x111",
            section_name: "SECTION A",
            section_staff_count: "v11111",
            section_id: "a1111",
            :
        },
        {
            section_hod: "x2222",
            section_name: "SECTION B",
            section_staff_count: "v2222",
            section_id: "a2222",
            :
        }
    ]
}
:
:
]
```

I wrote a mongodb query like as shown below

```
    db.getSiblingDB("departments").getCollection("DepartmentDetails").aggregate([
        { $unwind : "$sections"},
        { $match : { $and : [{ "sections.section_name" : "SECTION A"},
                    { $or : [{ "category" : "ABC"}]}]}},
        {$project : { "name" : "$sections.section_name", "hod" : "$sections.section_hod", "staff_count" : "$sections.section_staff_count", "id" : "$sections.section_id"}},
{$skip: 0}, {$limit: 10}
    ]);
```

which gives me a list of section details as shown below which contains `name`, `hod`, `staff_count`, `id` etc

```
[
    {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "hod": "xxxxx",
      "staff_count": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "yyyyy",
      "hod": "yyyyy",
      "staff_count": "yyyyy",
      "id": "yyyyy"
    }
    :
    :
    :
]
```

Everything looks good, but the problem is I have so many records in the list with which I am trying to build a pagination. For implementing pagination I know I can use the skip and limit function for iterating the pages, but for doing that I need to know the total counts of all the records.

I can do this in two ways, First way is I can execute two queries one which will be a count and then the aggregate query passing the skip and limit, second way is execute one query which return me the total counts and the documents in the order of first paginated page.

I am trying to implement the second way and bring the expected result is as shown below

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "hod": "xxxxx",
      "staff_count": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "yyyyy",
      "hod": "yyyyy",
      "staff_count": "yyyyy",
      "id": "yyyyy"
    }
    :
    :
    :
  ],
  "totalCount": 5444
}
```

Not sure if this is achievable. Can someone please help me on this. My default limit is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, it will give you total records and paginated results in one go,

```
db.getSiblingDB("departments").getCollection("DepartmentDetails")
    .aggregate([
        { $unwind : "$sections"},
        { $match : { $and : [{ "sections.section_name" : "SECTION A"},
        { $or : [{ "category" : "ABC"}]}]}},
        { 
            $project : { 
                "name" : "$sections.section_name", 
                "hod" : "$sections.section_hod", 
                "staff_count" : "$sections.section_staff_count", 
                "id" : "$sections.section_id"
            }    
        },
        {
            $facet: {
                metaData: [{
                    $count: 'total'
                }],
                records: [
                    {$skip: 0}, 
                    {$limit: 10}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                records: 1,
                total: {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            totalObj: { 
                                $arrayElemAt: ['$metaData', 0]           
                            }
                        },
                    in: '$$totalObj.total'
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but it gives me a metaData column with the data like `[{"_id": null, "totalRecords": new NumberInt("6233")}]`. Is there any other way to get it like  `{ "totalRecords": 62333}` instead of the previous data

Comment: also what's the difference between using `metaData: [{$group: {_id: null, totalRecords: { $sum: 1 }}}]` and  `total: [{ $count: 'total' }]`

Comment: @AlexMan I have updated the pipeline now it will give you the answer in your desire format.

Comment: Thanks for the update....the whole query takes around 7-10 seconds....do you feel any issue on this....

Comment: How many documents do you have in your collection?
And I don't see any reason to use $and and $or since there's only 1 object in it.
Can't we use {
  "sections.section_name": "SECTION A" ,
  "category": "ABC" 
} it will enhance some performance and as compare too $and and $or and have you build indexes in your db it will also increase the performance.

Comment: $match on first stage is best for performance but since we are using it at second stage after $unwind for obvious reasons it can hurt performance a very very little but still it's pretty fast.

Comment: I have total documents of 70K size in my collection

Comment: so you mean to say that I should place match before unwind ...correct?

Comment: No because it won't give you correct result then,
1. Update the query as I have mentioned above if you only have one object inside $or and $or.
2. Build indexes in your db for "category" and "sections.section_name"
It should enhance the performance,

Comment: Can you suggest something as a replacement for $unwind......the $unwind is taking a lot of time